# Breeze: how to tell if the query returned is from local cache or remote server?

Tags: breeze

I know you can call this function to query locally, if possible, or remotely. Is there a way to tell if the result is from local or remote? I remember I read something about it, but couldn't find it anymore.

```
manager.fetchEntityByKey('Employee', employeeID, true)
       .then(function(data) {
            employee(data.entity); 
       });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the 'fromCache' boolean property on the promise result.

```
manager.fetchEntityByKey('Employee', employeeID, true).then(function(data) {
   var employee = data.entity
   var wasFoundInCache = data.fromCache; 
});
```

See: http://www.breezejs.com/sites/all/apidocs/classes/EntityManager.html#method_fetchEntityByKey